# CSS custom list style type with numbering

Tags: html, css, list, styling

We can use the default CSS numbering style but is there a way that we can create our custom list that comes with numbering?

For example the default list we have:

```
1. Item
2. Item
3. Item
```

but what I'm looking for is something like this:

```
 (1) Item
 (2) Item
 (3) Item
```

Is it even possible?

These are the existing list-style-type:

http://codepen.io/impressivewebs/pen/fKjFL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it possible:

**CSS**

```
ol {
    counter-reset: section;
}
li{
    list-style: none;
}


li:before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: "(" counter(section)  " )";
}
```

Check the demo

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mukt0zrj/)**

Comment: Yes. proper `counter-reset` is what people mostly forget.

Answer (score 3):

You can acheive this with CSS "`Counter`" Concept. Below code will help you to do that.

```
<ol>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ol>


ol {list-style-type: none;}
li:before {content: "(" counter(section, decimal) ") ";}
li { counter-increment: section;}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvarthi/pqnu2Lj4/1/

Comment: +1, but you need to `counter-reset` in the `ol`. Otherwise, if any nested list items are there, they will also increment. See this to understand it better: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/pqnu2Lj4/2/

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is possible, have a look at this:

http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201105/styling_ordered_list_numbers/

Answer (score 0):

Following above posts, just added counter-reset for those who needs it:

```css
ol {list-style-type: none;  }
li:before {content: "(" counter(section, decimal) ") ";}
li { counter-increment: section;}
ol { counter-reset: section;  }
```

```html
<ol>
<li>Eyes</li>
<li>Hair
    <ol>
        <li>Straight</li>
        <li>Curly
            <ol>
                <li>Blonde</li>
                <li>Dark</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
    </li>
<li>Ears</li>
</ol>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/baltazarz3/sqqm9uav/1/